# bindParam error

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I use bindParam as in the flowing example but it gives me error

**The error** is Cannot get any response

```
$con = new PDO('odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server='.$db_ip.';Database='.$db_name,$db_user,$db_pass);

$m_id=585948;
$sql="select n_id from users where m_id = :member ";
$sth = $con->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindParam(':member', $m_id);
$sth->execute();

while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
echo $row['n_id'];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the connection to the **SQL Server** database is established ?

Comment: yes, Sparta and if i use the usual way where m_id = $m_id  it works

Comment: rather than an odbc driver could you ( or have you tried ) use the sql driver itself and then `$c = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=testdb", "UserName", "Password");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$sth = $con->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array(
    ':member', $m_id
));
```